# How many context “this” keyword has in C#?

Tags: c#, this

The keyword `this` in C# is slightly different from  other languages. I've been googling for a while, but I cannot find an article that will sum up all.

How can I use `this` in C#?

Comment: @Adam C++ as well. Except in C++ it's a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: Why don't you search the C# spec for the 'this' keyword?

Comment: @Adam no it doesn't it could be a reference or variable see my answer

Comment: @Jay yes I did and I shared what I gathered.

Comment: I would be more than happy If one can explain the downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is “this”? It is a keyword used in many object-oriented programming languages to refer to the current object. It can be implemented as a pointer (f.e. C++) or reference (f.e. Java), but in C# it has a few different meanings.

**Classes**

We can use “this” in 3 different contexts

- call other contructors
- refer to instance fields or methods
- pass current object

example:

```
public class Person
{
        private string name;

        public Person()
        {
            name = "John";
        }

        public Person(string name)
            : this() // call other constructor
        {
            // this is used to qualify the field
            // “name” is hidden by parameter
            this.name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }

        private void sayHi()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
            Foo.SayName(this); //use this to pass current object 
        }

        public void Speak()
        {
            this.sayHi(); // use this to refer to an instance method
            Console.WriteLine("Want to come up and see my etchings? ");
        }
    }

class Foo 
{
    public static void SayName(Person person)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My name is  {0}", person.Name);
    }
}
```

**Indexers**

Define an indexer for the type to have array-like semantics.

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get { return array[index]; }
    set { array[index] = value; }
}
```

**Extension methods**

```
class Foo 
{  
    // with “this” modifiler we can use it like instance method of Person
    public static void SayName(this Person person) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“My name is  {0}”, person.Name);
    }
}
```

**Structures**

```
struct MyVeryOwnInteger 
{
    private int x;
    public int Gimme() 
{
       // inside struct this is treated as a variable
       // not reference to current structure 
        return this.x; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two meanings for "this." The "this" that you are (I am assuming) familiar with, which is the keyword which refers to the current instance of the class you are in, and then as a keyword in an extension method:

e.g.,

```
public static void SomeExtensionMethod(this string foo)
{
  ///stuff
}
```

In this latter case, the "this" keyword is used to denote that you are adding an extension method to the strong class.

Answer (score 0):

You use it in this manner:

Say you have a class where you have a variable that is the same name as the the parameter you are giving to a method, when you want to refer to the variable outside the method and in this class you use `this.variable`.

Example:

```
class C:
    private str var;
    public C(string var)
    {
        this.var = var;
    }
```

As I said, `this.var` refers to the "outer" string and `var` refers to the string in the cointext of the method, in this case the constructor.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is very clear and has some good examples.